# Trouble getting Ids passed into a set for use in a method

Tags: trigger, method, set, reference

Having trouble getting a trigger to pass values into a method.  Does it have something to do with using __r for a few fields?  When I look at the debug for actIds set, it is null.  However, when I check the debug, it looks like it is still going through the method for some reason, but with no values.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!  I may have copy/pasted too much code below, but I'm having trouble pinpointing where the problem is occurring.

```
trigger AccountContactRoleTrigger on Account_Contact_Role__c (after insert, after update) {
if(trigger.isInsert){
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> mAccountIdToContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
    Set<Id> actIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account_Contact_Role__c acr : trigger.new){
        if(acr.Billing_Contact__c != null){
            if(mAccountIdToContacts.containsKey(acr.Account__r.Id)){
                List<Contact> cList = mAccountIdToContacts.get(acr.Account__r.Id); 
                cList.add(acr.Contact__r);
                mAccountIdToContacts.put(acr.Account__r.Id, cList);
            }
            else{
                List<Contact> cList = new List<Contact>();
                cList.add(acr.Contact__r);
                mAccountIdToContacts.put(acr.Account__r.Id, cList);
                actIds.add(acr.Account__r.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    if(actIds.size() > 0 && actIds != null){
        system.debug(mAccountIdToContacts);
        system.debug(actIds);
        ContactClass.CreateOpportunityRoles(mAccountIdToContacts, actIds);
    }
}
```

EDIT:  Class code here:

```
public with sharing class AccountContactRoleClass {
public static void CreateOpportunityRoles(Map<Id, List<Contact>> mAccountIdToContacts, Set<Id> actIds){
    List<OpportunityContactRole> ocrList = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    List<Opportunity> oList = [Select Id, LOB_Brand__c From Opportunity Where LOB_Brand__c in: actIds];
    for(Opportunity o : oList){
        List<Contact> contactList = mAccountIdToContacts.get(o.LOB_Brand__c);
        if(contactList != null && contactList.size() > 0){
            for(Contact c : contactList){
                String role = c.Billing_Contact__c;
                OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole(Role = role, OpportunityId = o.Id, ContactId = c.Id);
                ocrList.add(ocr);
            }
        }
    }

    if(ocrList.size() > 0){
        insert ocrList;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As an aside, `if(actIds.size() > 0 && actIds != null)` is overly protective, and even if it were not, it is written incorrectly. The point of checking against null is to avoid NullPointerException errors when an object may be uninitialized. So you'd write `if(actIds != null && actIds.size() > 0)`. But, since you clearly initialize the variable on line 4, it's not magically going to become null again, so you can just write `if(actIds.size() > 0)`. Finally, it's usually easier to read something as empty or not empty, so you can write `if(!actIds.isEmpty())`, which makes the meaning clearer.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense ... I had it that way originally, but was trying to figure out why IDs were not being passed in, but it seemed the method was still being invoked.  Your explanation is a great help - I'll take you up on using empty for scenarios like this moving forward.  I'll upvote it as soon as I reach 15 reputation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - related fields are not included in Triggers - you would need to re-query for them. But not sure why you need them in your example - you can just reference the AccountId by doing this:

```
acr.Account__c
```

The Contact list is probably more tricky - not sure what data you need in your method, but I don't think the List will contain anything beyond the Id, so I think you just need to pass in the ContactIds and re-query in your ContactClass method

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!  Was hoping it was something simple that I was just missing :)

We're getting a null pointer exception on insert now, line 9 of our class, where we reference a field on the contact.  Does this have to do with what you're mentioning above - do we need to have a query for these values within the trigger?  EDIT:  Added class code up above.

Comment: *sorry - a query within the class, like you suggested.

Comment: Correct - Billing_Contact__c is not going to be available in that context - you would need to query for the Contacts passed in and then you'll be able to access fields on the Contact for this purpose